# What can cause intermittent javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching <host> found?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

For the past few weeks, I've been getting occasional reports of the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching vassalengine.org found.
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:370)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:200)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1500)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1415)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1161)
    at VASSAL.tools.version.LiveVersionInfo.getVersion(LiveVersionInfo.java:52)
    at VASSAL.tools.version.LiveVersionInfo.getRelease(LiveVersionInfo.java:38)
    at VASSAL.tools.version.VersionUtils.compareReportable(VersionUtils.java:38)
    at VASSAL.tools.BugDialog$CheckRequest.doInBackground(BugDialog.java:487)
    at VASSAL.tools.BugDialog$CheckRequest.doInBackground(BugDialog.java:473)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:343)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching vassalengine.org found.
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:212)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:452)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:238)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

The relevant part of `VASSAL.tools.version.LiveVersionInfo.getVersion()` is this:

```
    try (InputStream in = new URL(url).openStream()) {
      return IOUtils.toString(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).trim();
    }
```

where `url == "https://vassalengine.org/util/current-release"`.

If I visit that URL in a browser and check the certificate, the CN is `vassalengine.org` and the only Subject Alt Name listed is `vassalengine.org`. If I run the code myself, it succeeds; there is no exception thrown. Hundreds of other users have also successfully run this code. I've also had people who have reported this error run a diagnostic program containing just the code above... and none of them have been able to reproduce the error when they do that.

What could be causing a transient error like this?

Comment: It would be nice to capture the actual certificate that is sent that causes this error. Also, it would be nice to know what version of Java these error reports are coming from, in case somehow an old version of Java is implicated. I was thinking this might be due to the client not sending the servername indication extension (SNI) for some reason, perhaps because it dates from before that was implemented.

Comment: When I try send a client hello **without** SNI the server responds with a certificate whose subjectAltName is `forum.vassalengine.org`. Might be meaningful.

Comment: The version of Java we've been having these reports with is 17.0.1. (I can't say if we'd get reports from other versions, because this is the only version we've bundled since we switched to using HTTPS for the URL.) `forum.vassalengine.org` has its own cert and is on the same IP. I wasn't aware we needed to do anything special to make Java use SNI, though. Do we? Got any suggestions for how to capture the cert when the error happens?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything special to get Java to use SNI, I'm just throwing out wild-ass guesses, in this case that somehow, for some unknown reason, the client hello is being sent without SNI. It's because of SNI that you can host multiple domains on the same IP and use HTTPS. I don't know how to capture the cert when the error happens. I be tempted to capture the exception, then redo the request turning off hostname matching just for the purpose of capturing and logging the cert.

Comment: Wild-ass guesses are useful at this point; that's basically what I've got myself. :)

Comment: Setting the `javax.net.debug` system property to something like `ssl:handshake` or `ssl:handshake:trustmanager:verbose` should pretty much **tell** you what's happening when your connection fails.  The problem is probably going to be linking the messages to the failed attempt and/or filling up your filesystem with log files.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Can that property be reset at runtime? If so, then I could catch the error, turn on the logging, and retry the connection in order hopefully to see it fail again, but with full logging.

Comment: Turns out that yes, you can set `javax.net.debug` at runtime and have it take effect. This should give us a way to get some diagnostic information next time someone reports this problem.

Comment: I would appreciate an update if you track this down, I'm curious.

Comment: I will report back what I find, but it might be a bit; the diagnostic I wrote won't go out until our next release, which is likely to be a few weeks away, and then we have to wait for somebody to report the problem again after that.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this; the release with the diagnostic output is out, but I haven't had any reports from it yet.

Comment: ...and still no reports. Sigh.